# Bypassing built-in browser authentication when making HTTP calls from embedded Applet

Tags: java, security, browser, applet, camera

- I have a simple web page with an
  embedded Java applet.
- The applet
  makes HTTP calls to different Axis
  Cameras who all share the same
  authentication (e.g. username,
  password).
- I am passing the user name and password to the Java code upon launch of the applet - no problem.
- When I run from within NetBeans with the applet viewer, I get full access to the cameras and see streaming video - exactly as advertised.
- The problem begins when I open the HTML page in a web browser (Firefox).
- Even though my code handles authentication:

  ```
  URL u = new URL(useMJPGStream ? mjpgURL : jpgURL);
  huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();


  String base64authorization = 
      securityMan.getAlias(this.securityAlias).getBase64authorization();
  // if authorization is required set up the connection with the encoded 
  // authorization-information
  if(base64authorization != null)
  {
      huc.setDoInput(true);
      huc.setRequestProperty("Authorization",base64authorization);
      huc.connect();
  }

  InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();
  connected = true;
  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
  dis= new DataInputStream(bis);
  ```
- The browser still brings up an authentication pop-up and requests the username and password for each camera separately!
- To make things worse, the images displayed from the camera are frozen and old (from last night).
- How can I bypass the browser's authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Fixed***

I added the following lines:

```
huc.setDoOuput(true);
huc.setUseCaches(false);
```

after the

```
huc.setDoInput(true);
```

line.

Answer (score 0):

When running in the browser `base64authorization` not null, correct?

I'm not really sure what `getBase64authorization` is supposed to return, but I'm fairly certain when you call `huc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", **autorization value**)` it's looking for a HTTP Basic authentication value.  Meaning `**authorization value**` needs to be in the format `Basic **base 64 encoding of username:password**` as described [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip47.html).

Maybe you just need to add the `Basic` (note the trailing space) string to your property.

Comment: Apparently not.  I see you fixed it!

Comment: Thank you Vinnie - but I was already doing that (I know you could not have known w/o my code).

My solution posted above worked!