# Applet displays login dialog if basic authentication used

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet, basic-authentication

I have a Java applet inserted on a webpage:

```
applet = '<embed'
    + ' type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"'
    + ' pluginspage = "http://www.java.com/en/download/"'
    + ' width="0" height="0"'
    + ' style="position: absolute"'
    + ' archive="/plugins/MyApplet.jar"'
    + ' code="MyTestApplet.class"'
    + '>'

appletContainer.innerHTML = applet;
```

The server is using Basic authentication. When Chrome or Safari (or better say JVM) requests the MyApplet.jar file the 'Authentication Required' dialog is displayed, that is very annoying.

[image: Authentication Required' dialog is displayed when requesting .jar file]

I have found that Chrome/Safari (or JVM) does not attach the 'Authentication: Basic' header to GET request automatically for some reason.

Any idea how to force the Authentication: Basic header to be attached when requesting .jar file to avoid this extra login dialog?

Comment: Make said applet resources not protected by auth? I do not think that which is being asked for can be achieved.

Comment: And what if you run it with a standard applet tags or jnlp?

Comment: +1 on the [JNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), but for writing the applet element, I'd use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).

Comment: Are you sure the applet's Java code isn't opening an HTTP connection back to the server, and *that* isn't the source of your problem.  For example:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366223/bypassing-built-in-browser-authentication-when-making-http-calls-from-embedded-ap

Comment: @paulsm4. No my applet does not make any calls to server. I have examined requests with fiddler and found that the issue is in GET request to jar file.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson. As far as I know deployJava.js does not support dynamic insertion of an applet to a page. I need first to insert it on a page dynamically and than remove at some point.

Comment: @user592704. If you mean using <applet> tag - it is not an option. If Java is not installed (or if it is outdated), Applet tag toes not trigger the "Download Java" dialog.

Comment: So the applet jar is not in the same dir as its html runner "archive="../plugins/MyApplet.jar" ?

Comment: @user592704 yes, it is in a separate folder, but withing the same domain.

Comment: And it sounds like "plugins" is configured to require "auth" access.  You need to change it to allow anonymous access, or more your .jar to a different directory (one that allows anonymous access).

Comment: @paulsm4. There are no directory with anonymous access on this website, and I do not have any control over this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the problem might be that your applet is trying to open a connection back to the server, the server is protected by basic authentication.  If so, you'd need to do something like this in your applet:

```
  // http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AppletsFaq#authentication
  String authorization = Base64Coder.encode(username + ":" + password);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
```

Otherwise, just move your .jar file to a directory on the server that allows anonymous read access.

Comment: No, my applet does not make any connections to server. The GET request to jar file triggers the above login dialog, I see this in fiddler logs.

Comment: OK, then you need to allow anonymous read access to "plugins".  Or move it to a different directory, with anonymous read access.  Pst and I both said this yesterday: "Make said applet resources not protected by auth"

Comment: No paulsm4, giving anonymous access to any files including .jar is not an option in my case. I do not have access to server and can not configure permissions.

Comment: I have same situation as you described in answer - my applet try connect to servlet from which it was loaded. But after some time I always get 401 error response code. How you think, does your solution will help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see it, it is not an applet authentification as it is but a host/domain one just because the JVM (watch Oracle lable) itself is asking for login; perhaps it means that your html is trying to get the jar from a forbidden location or the path is being misstaking as an absolute one; but if it is an absolute one like the /plugins/MyApplet.jar so where is the domain root then? I am not pretty sure but have you tried to put down path like "archive="../plugins/MyApplet.jar" with double dots in its prefix?

And I just wondering is the "/plugins" folder a web one? If it is the problem may be much deeper than Java itself. It may be the domain inner web folders access policy (like a no sub folders access) or something which should be controlled by sys admin.

As a way about, try to put your jar into the same folder as its html file is. Maybe the domain security policy allows your client computer use the only one web folder only

Comment: /plugins/ folder has the same permissions as other locations on this website. There is no way to specify relative path (../somepath/) because the plugin can appear on many pages with various locations.

Comment: Both the server and client computer are not on the domain and both has default configuration with no policy changes.

Comment: And what are the default configuration? Just for a test put your jar at the same location as its html